# PHP/AJAX forms not working with load balancer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, load-balancing

I have two servers running behind one load balancer.

My websites have contact forms.

When the "Submit" button is pressed, a jQuery script is called with AJAX, which redirects to a PHP file, which sends the e-mail.

The forms work perfectly and function properly when there is only one server - however, when there are two or more servers, the forms do not work at **ALL**. I keep searching for a solution but haven't found one.

Is there something I need to know about PHP, AJAX, and load balancers that will help me fix this issue?

Comment: Nginx load balancing server?

Comment: AWS load balancer, server running Apache.

Comment: Do you have sessions in your php files, or are these php files session less

Comment: Try deleting all the cookies from the domain because they might use "sticky session persistence" http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-sticky-sessions.html

Comment: No sessions in the PHP files.

Comment: I just added a "Load Balancer Stickiness Policy" to attempt to combat this issue. I have a dev server running that's only ONE server, and it works if I direct all AJAX calls to the send form on the dev server. Unfortunately, the Dev server goes down on nights and weekends, so that's not a solution for me.

Comment: No errors returned or logged anywhere?

Comment: Are you sure it is a load balancer problem? Without sessions that should be irrelevant. Making it irrelevant is what restful is all about. I think you should focus your question on why my form is not being processed or why my emails are not being sent. I love crystal ball questions, but honestly they are rather difficult to solve. Try to pin down the issue by doing some proper tracing first. Take a look at the logs. Run xdebug in remote mode and throw some breakpoints in there. Then come back with (a) more specific question(s).

Comment: (http://xdebug.org/docs/remote)

Comment: @NotGaeL All my servers and files are completed identical. DEV is running behind a load balancer, and PROD 1 and PROD 2 are running behind another load balancer. DEV forms are working, and PROD 1 & 2 forms are not working. I assume the issue is due to the load balancer balancing multiple servers.

Comment: Do not assume. Programming is not a religion (I have nothing against validated assumptions, though)

Comment: Here is an assumption: You are load balancing apache instances. Those instances would then process your php code through a mod_php/mod_fcgid/mod_fastcgi+php_fpm configuration. Are you sure that configuration is right?

Comment: Another assumption: What about the sendmail configuration in your php path? I remember having to add an extra parameter to the command when I switched from sendmail to postix (http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/02/06/configure-postfixsendmail-for-php-mail-in-ubuntu/). Also I rembember having to add extra iptables configuration. And WS EC2 is also quite strict with the default instance ports policy (more for incomming than outgoing connections but still...)

Comment: Also: are your SPF records properly configured? Maybe you app is sending emails but they are being filtered out by the intermediate mx servers, not even reaching the destination's spam folder (that is quite common with cloud VMs without a properly configured associated domain: http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/07/sending-email-from-ec2.html)

Comment: Thanks for the resources. As far as spam, Dev and Prod are both EC2 instances behind load balancers sending out mail. It can't be in the PHP code itself, as they're identical. Everything shares the same AMI. It must be some configuration that's different, either in the EC2 instances, load balancer configuration, or security config somewhere along the way.

Comment: @NotGael in case you were wondering, my live ELB did not have a public IP, and that's why the mail wasn't going out.